# Adding a second column caused an error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In my database i have 1 column, i intercede to her my ArrayList and everything works.

```
    for(LatLng s : list1)
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('"+s+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
```

Now i want another column "ID" with `auto increment`, so i make this in `phpmyadmin`.
  Name `ID`, type `int` with `auto increment`.
But now with 2 column, my method didn't work.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please take a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: You can't simply add columns like that.

Comment: Please don't concatenate values into a query like this; it leaves you open to SQL injection, and other subtle problems. Please [learn how to use prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more then one column you should indicate the column  name

```
"INSERT INTO table1 (your_column_name)  VALUES('"+s+"')"
```

Comment: Being such high rep users ... do you really want to answer this type of questions?

Comment: Seem that nobody else give an answer .. so  . i hope this is useful for the OP

Comment: Please see the comment from @juergend. Personally I won't post an answer for this question.

Comment: I have see  the comment  and i  think that for a new user  is better   a clear sample ..

Comment: I am a new programmer and i understand only clear sample, thank you very much for answer.